# C#: Output a random element of a list into specific textboxes

Tags: c#, list, random

I'm trying to make a program which outputs a random element of a list into the specific textbox.

[image: img]

If I press the button, every textBox should now contain a random element of each List specific to their category. So textBox 3 should output an element of the Body List.

```
List <string> Sex = new List<string>;
Sex.Add("Male");
Sex.Add("Female");

List <string> Head = new List<string>;
Head.Add("Square");
// ...
Head.Add("Odd");

List <string> Body = new List<string>;
Body.Add("Fat");
// ...
Body.Add("Model");

List <string> Features = new List<string>;
Features.Add("Cane");
// ...
Features.Add("Backpack");

List <string> Time = new List<string>;
Time.Add("Victorian");
// ...
Time.Add("World War II");

List <string> Setting = new List<string>;
Setting.Add("Caught stealing");
// ...
Setting.Add("In a lonely forest");
```

So how would I do this? I tried using the Random function but I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers You don't need to do all that Add Add Add, you can just use a collection initializer

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
void randomTextfunction(TextBox targetTextbox, List<String> sourceList) {
  var r = new Random();
  targetTextBox.Text = sourceList[r.Next(sourceList.Count - 1)];
 }
```

You should validate that the source list actually contains any entries.

Edit:
As noted by *Rufus L* the Random-object should be instantiated outside of the function.

Comment: One suggestion would be to define and instantiate `'r'` at the class level rather than re-create it each time this method is called. If called in quick succession, like in a loop (which is highly likely), `'r'` will be created with the same seed value each time and will return the same item for every call.